# javaScript - remove event from certain links

Tags: javascript, events, flexslider

I can't figure out how to remove an event listener from an element on my page. This event is causing issues between two scripts and it would be great to get rid of it!

Here's how it's added;

```
if (CT_I_EnableExitTracking) {
    if (document.addEventListener) //handle DOM 2 (Mozilla 6)
        document.addEventListener('click', CT_ProcClick, false);
    else
        document.attachEvent('onclick', CT_ProcClick);
}
```

..and it needs removing from this markup (from the flexslider 2 plugin)..

```
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

The links inside this div are the issue. How can I target them? I've tried various ideas but I just don't seem to get the syntax right (too much time with jQuery and no real jS knowledge I think!!)

```
var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-prev");
prev.removeEventListener('click', CT_ProcClick, false);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning event listener to `document` object while you try to remove event listener from `flex-prev`.

In addition, `document.getElementsByClassName("flex-prev")` returns a NodeList. In this case you should either loop that through:
`[].forEach.call(prev, function(obj, i) { ... });`
or reference to single instance with:
`document.getElementsByClassName("flex-prev")[0]`.

But in your case, you should make a check on the event listener's function whether the event.target has class "flex-prev". Like this:

```
function CT_ProcClick(evt) {
  var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  if (!!~target.className.indexOf("flex-prev")) {
    return false;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, if use.removeEventListener is placed after addEventListener has been used (lower down in the script), does this still work, or must I never do this?